# Why do I get "write permission" errors installing Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

When I use `rvm use 1.9.2`, I get Rails v3.0.0:

```
vikas@admin1-DL-H61MXEL:~$ rvm use 1.9.2 --default
Using /home/vikas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320
vikas@admin1-DL-H61MXEL:~$ rails -v
Rails 3.0.0
```

When I use `rvm use 2.0.0`, I get Rails v3.2.13:

```
vikas@admin1-DL-H61MXEL:~$ rvm use 2.0.0
Using /home/vikas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195
vikas@admin1-DL-H61MXEL:~$ rails -v
Rails 3.2.13
```

I need Rails v3.2.13 with Ruby 1.9.2.

When I used `rvm use 1.9.2 --default` and `gem install rails -v 3.2.13`, I got the following error:

```
While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError) You don't have write permissions into the /home/vikas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin directory. 

This is the error I'm facing now.
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The most likely reason you're getting the error:

```
(Gem::FilePermissionError) You don't have write permissions into the /home/vikas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin directory.
```

Is because, at some point, you used `sudo` or were running as root when you use RVM to install a gem. When that happened, the ownership of files and/or folders changed to root's permissions, which you can't override running as you.

You don't want to run as root, or use `sudo` *EVER* when running `rvm` or `gem` commands if you have a RVM installation to provide Ruby in a sandbox in your home directory.

To fix this, try this command:

```
sudo chown -R vikas ~/.rvm
```

That will use `sudo` to change ownership of all files in the ~/.rvm directory to your own account, from the "root" user. This will take at least a few seconds so let it run.

Once that has run, you should be able to switch to each of your Rubies and delete the installed Rails:

```
rvm use 1.9.2
gem uninstall rails
gem install rails -v 3.2.13
```

Then:

```
rvm use 2.0.0
gem uninstall rails
gem install rails -v [whatever version you want]
gem install rails -v
```

Answer (score 0):

```
rvm use 1.9.2 --default Using /home/vikas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320 
gem install rails -v 3.2.13
```

Comment: While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions into the /home/vikas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin directory. this is the error im facing now

Comment: That's a file permission issue, either login with the user vikas to do the installation of the gem, or do a system installation of rvm and install the version of rails later.

Answer (score 0):

rvm is software tool by which you can manage multiple version of rubies on your system.

for each ruby version you can create a gemset which is just a group of gems.

each ruby version you install has a  'default' gemset.

and it seems that you have installed rails 3.0 for ruby 1.9.2 and rails 3.2.13 for ruby 2.0

you can create your own gemset by command

```
rvm gemset create rails3
```

this will create a gemset named 'rails3' and to use it you have to do

```
rvm gemset use rails3
```

and in this gemset you can install any version of rails you want.

with command

```
gem install rails -v='3.2.13'
```

for more info see rvm doc.

https://rvm.io/