# install jekyll in linux mint

Tags: ruby, linux, rvm

I tried to install jekyll on my `Linux heavenpc 3.16.0-38-generic #52~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 8 09:43:57 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

I have appropriate suplementary packages installed:

```
god@heavenpc ~ $ ruby -v
ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-linux]
god@heavenpc ~ $ rvm -v
rvm 1.27.0 (master) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
god@heavenpc ~ $ gem -v
2.5.1
```

But can't install jekyll:

```
god@heavenpc ~ $ gem install jekyll
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /home/god/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0 directory.
god@heavenpc ~ $ sudo gem install jekyll
ERROR:  Error installing jekyll:
    jekyll requires Ruby version >= 2.0.0.
```

I have another ruby but it is not default (and rvm doesn't show it):

```
god@heavenpc ~ $ whereis ruby
ruby: /usr/bin/ruby /usr/bin/ruby2.0 /usr/lib/ruby /usr/bin/X11/ruby /usr/bin/X11/ruby2.0 /usr/share/man/man1/ruby.1.gz
god@heavenpc ~ $ cd /usr/bin/ && ./ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p551 (2014-11-13) [x86_64-linux] Brightbox
god@heavenpc /usr/bin $ rvm list rubies

rvm rubies

=* ruby-2.3.0 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

Seems that this not default ruby is used while installing jekyll. I tried all approaches i've googled but nothing helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add write permissions to .rvm folder
`chown -R god ~/.rvm`. Then try `gem install jekyll`

`sudo gem install jekyll` is using the system wide ruby in your case. So, another option is to update ruby using `apt-get` and then do `sudo gem install jekyll`.

Comment: Thank you.   
I added permissions. Checked with:   
`$ ls -ld ~/.rvm`. Output: `drwxr-xr-x 26 god god 4096 апр.   1 20:25 /home/god/.rvm`
Unfortunately I have the same `You don't have write permissions` message.   
My ruby is upgraded. Seems that 1.9 is the last in repo.  
Have any ideas?

Comment: @rocknow How about if you do `sudo chown -R god ~/.rvm`? and then install `gem install jekyll`

Comment: Oh God! It works! Thank you very much! It would be great if you tell me some details about first command from last comment. Does it mean that I gave write permission for `god` user?

Comment: I can award bounty in 21 hours so we have to wait.

Comment: `chown -R god ~/.rvm` makes `god` the owner of files and directories recursively.

Comment: @rocknow, I think the key here is recursively. This question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17463151/why-do-i-get-write-permission-errors-installing-rails. I got the idea of `-R` from there and top answer there is a lot better. I am not sure how to close it.